# Structure C++ , dynamic names construction

Tags: c++, dynamic, structure

I have constructed a struct in a C++ class, 
Lets sat it is called Task

I would like to initiate a new constructed based on an index that might change every time I run the program, for example

```
for ( i=1; i<=index,++i){

 Task ai;
}
```

this way after the loop I would like to have structures named a1, a2, a3 ,a4,...an

How can I add the number i to the end of the name as a part of it.

Comment: +1. There are probably some ways to do stuff like this with the preprocessor, but arrays are the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned you could use an `std::vector<Task>`, although I would probably just use a dynamically allocated array:

```
Task* tasks = new Task[index];
task[0] ...
task[1] ...

delete[] tasks;
```

Comment: A vector *is* a dynamically-allocated array, with the ownership concerns abstracted away from the unsuspecting programmer!

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not have reflection, so you can't dynamically create variable names like this. However, arrays/vectors are useful here:

```
std::vector<Task> tasks(ai); // a vector of ai x Task objects
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a std::vector < Task > ai and add it to the vector. This would solve the problem of  varying index too.

Comment: std::vector< Task > *ai = new vector< Task >(); for( i= 0; i < index; i++ ) { ai->push_back( Task struct ); }

Comment: Why in the world would you want to dynamically allocate a vector?

Comment: That code is not valid and there is also no need to dynamically-allocate. Not to mention repeatedly pushing back is inefficient, and pointless when you know the size beforehand. Try `std::vector<Task> ai(index);`

Comment: I know that code is not valid C++ compilable code. I just gave it as a skeleton so that details can be filled in as needed. Well, the need for dynamic allocation arises because in the question "based on an index that might change every time" . If I understand correctly push_back is similar to an array assignment unless ofcourse if there is no resize of vector at that point.